# Angular: Testing HTTP with MockBackend, is async() really required?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-testing

I'm using `MockBackend` to test code that depends in `@angular/http`.
All the examples around the web use an asynchronous test setup, like here:
[thoughtram: Testing Services with Http in Angular](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/11/28/testing-services-with-http-in-angular-2.html#making-the-test-asynchronous)

```js
describe('getVideos()', () => {

  it('should return an Observable<Array<Video>>',
      async(inject([VideoService, MockBackend], (videoService, mockBackend) => {

      videoService.getVideos().subscribe((videos) => {
        expect(videos.length).toBe(4);
        expect(videos[0].name).toEqual('Video 0');
        expect(videos[1].name).toEqual('Video 1');
        expect(videos[2].name).toEqual('Video 2');
        expect(videos[3].name).toEqual('Video 3');

        expect("THIS TEST IS FALSE POSITIVE").toEqual(false); 
      });

      const mockResponse = {
        data: [
          { id: 0, name: 'Video 0' },
          { id: 1, name: 'Video 1' },
          { id: 2, name: 'Video 2' },
          { id: 3, name: 'Video 3' }
        ]
      };

      mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection) => {
        connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({
          body: JSON.stringify(mockResponse)
        })));
      });
  })));
});
```

However, I tried that out and I’m pretty sure that MockBackend executes completely synchronous:

```js
describe('getVideos()', () => {

  it('should return an Observable<Array<Video>>',
    inject([VideoService, MockBackend], (videoService, mockBackend) => {

      const mockResponse = {
        data: [
          { id: 0, name: 'Video 0' },
          { id: 1, name: 'Video 1' },
          { id: 2, name: 'Video 2' },
          { id: 3, name: 'Video 3' },
        ]
      };

      mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection) => {
        connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({
          body: JSON.stringify(mockResponse)
        })));
      });

      let videos;
      videoService.getVideos().subscribe(v => videos = v);

      // synchronous code!?
      expect(videos.length).toBe(4);
      expect(videos[0].name).toEqual('Video 0');
      expect(videos[1].name).toEqual('Video 1');
      expect(videos[2].name).toEqual('Video 2');
      expect(videos[3].name).toEqual('Video 3');
    }));
});
```

I created a full example on plunker here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/I3N9zL?p=preview

[image]

Something must have been changed since those articles were written.
Can somebody point me to that breaking change? Or did I missed an important fact?

Comment: Altering passing tests and having them still pass isn't necessarily useful - what happens if you take a *failing* test using `async` and remove that call? Does it still fail?

Comment: first example is basically wrong,
`expect("THIS TEST IS FALSE POSITIVE").toEqual(false);` should never be green. it would work, if the code would run async. but it does not (anymore).

Comment: I propose that the ***mockResponse*** is synchronous, but ***MockConnection*** does not seem to be synchronous. I added a second test to each test (reducing it to 2 videos, and the synchronous one failed and the async passed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you're completely right with your assumption, that `MockConnection.mockRespond()` emits synchronous. `async()` is not needed in this particular test.

I'm the author of the article you've referred to in your question and I've updated it accordingly.

Thank you so much for pointing this out!